# Using requests-html how to create async functions in loop and call them on single run function

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I want to be able to create as many `async` functions as possible and to run them at once using `requests-html` library.

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
number=5
for i in range(1,number):
    async def get_pythonorg():
        r = await asession.get('site/{}'.format(i))
        return r

results = asession.run(call All the above created functions called by a loop)
```